# Where do zombies come from?

Tags: history-of, zombie, undead

Who was the first writer/movie director/artist that came with the idea of the zombies we see in movies nowadays like Resident Evil, World War Z, Walking Dead? In general: the idea of a person seemed dead but that walks and just bites people and then turn them into zombies as well.

It seems very widespread now, but I don't know where does it came from. Was it a book, a movie, a computer game? Was Resident Evil (as far as I concerned, the first one to introduce this type of undead?

Comment: You're going to have to narrow this down: stories about the undead seem to pre-date written mythology. Zombies as a specific kind of undead are more recent and if that's your question then please make it more clear what kind of undead you're asking about (there are a lot of very different things which get called "zombie," and most of the modern ideas of the zombie come from sources unrelated to the origin of the name itself).

Comment: @BESW Thanks for the heads up, I just edited the question. I'm referring to modern zombies like Resident Evil.

Comment: What is it about Resident Evil zombies that sets them apart to you? Their level of intelligence, their speed, their resilience, their scientific cause?

Comment: Resident Evil is far from the first. A much better choice (and I'm not sure if it is the first, but certainly early) would be Romero's _Night of the Living Dead_.

Comment: @PauloBu: your idea of zombie as mentioned in first part of your question can be easily confused with vampires. The main difference b/w a vampire and a zombie is that zombies can survive daylight whereas vampires can not.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zombie

Comment: George Romero's seminal work, _The Night of the Living Dead_?

Comment: I just set the Resident Evil's example because was the first I could think of. I was just trying to get some education about the topic which so far, I am getting.

Comment: @Madeyedexter: It's true it can be confused, but I am emphasizing in the word **zombie**. Also, the main difference I see between zombies and vampires is that vampires keep their intelligence and improve their senses and motions skills, zombies behave just like animals.

Comment: When a mommy zombie and a daddy zombie love each other very much...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At least in film, the first "modern" zombies, **the literal dead walking again** (as opposed to voodoo and other drug and / or hypnotic states) appear a couple years before Night of the Living Dead. A Hammer film from 1966, [Plague of the Zombies](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0060841/combined), was the first film to show corpses [rising out of their graves](http://www.cathoderaytube.co.uk/2012/06/british-cult-classics-plague-of-zombies.html), digging through the earth, to walk again.

While this is the herald of the modern "truly-dead" zombie, it wasn't until 1968 and George A. Romero that the idea of the "**real**" modern zombie (actually dead *and* eating the living) appeared and took root. The fact they weren't called zombies is moot. They were zombies as sure as Nosferatu was a vampire. Also this is only taking into account multiple numbers of zombies. I don't know the earliest film (or other) reference to a singular cursed or other-wise revived person.

And as for Gilgamesh, that is more parable or metaphor. It is not the dead being brought back as rotting corpses (admittedly my understanding of the Epic is sketchy at best). It seems to be the dead being released. I do think there is a difference. Same reason people *generally* don't think of Lazarus or Jesus to be zombies.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. **Really interesting**. I liked a lot your opinions!

Answer (score 4):

This one seems to go back to the Epic of Gilgamesh; see http://www.ancienttexts.org/library/mesopotamian/gilgamesh/tab6.htm

> I will knock down the Gates of the Netherworld,
>   I will smash the door posts, and leave the doors flat down,
>   and will let the dead go up to eat the living!
>   And the dead will outnumber the living!

This contains most of the core ideas; zombies rising from the dead and eating living people are all here.  It's a full-fledged zombie apocalypse right from the dawn of literature, in other words.

The idea of an undead creature that bites a living person thereby turning them into another undead is certainly from the vampire myth, which is - again - [older than dirt](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/OlderThanDirt) (obligatory TV Tropes warning).

Comment: Thank you very much. Your answer is really interesting.

Comment: Explanation of the TV Tropes warning for those (un)lucky to not know it - http://xkcd.com/609/.

Answer (score 1):

The idea of the modern zombie, i.e. a horde of reanimated half-rotten corpses that try to eat the living and (sometimes) convert their victims to new zombies, usually accompanied by the collapse of civilization as a setting, is sometimes acknowledged to have been invented by George Romero in his movie *Night of the Living Dead*.

[From Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Night_Of_The_Living_Dead#Influence) (emphasis mine):

> Romero revolutionized the horror film genre with Night of the Living Dead; according to Almar Haflidason of the BBC, the film represented "a new dawn in horror film-making".The film has also effectively redefined the use of the term "zombie". **While the word "zombie" itself is never used - the word used in the film is ghoul - Romero's film introduced the theme of zombies as reanimated, flesh-eating cannibals**. Early zombie films like Victor Halperin's White Zombie (1932) and Jacques Tourneur's I Walked with a Zombie (1943) concerned living people enslaved by a Voodoo witch doctor; many were set in the Caribbean.

Romero himself is said to have been influenced by the book *I Am Legend*, where the creatures are actually vampires.

Comment: I see, thanks for the answer. It seems George Romero is appointed to be the _modern zombie's stories_ father. But actually the behavior pattern exists long time ago.